# Transfer http to https in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've been using more method transfers http to https. But I have  a problem
When typing the name of the site, It is always show http: //  but When I try to type https: // mywesite.com  is still work
Now, I want my webite is always appear https when user typing my website

[image: code example, pasted as a graphic]

[image: code example, pasted as a graphic]

Comment: Do you have a SSL?

Comment: sounds like you need a page rule to force all traffic to https:

Comment: You should put your code in the question, not as a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption is accomplished by the web server, not Wordpress. When the server receives your HTTP request, it can forward your browser to HTTPS.

- [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) means HTTP Secure. Security is accomplished by using an SSL certificate to encrypt transmitted data.
- Unless you are actually using SSL, you shouldn't rewrite `http` to `https`, because that will falsely imply the connection is secure.

[HTTPS Documentation](https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is just to mask the URL without having a SSL.

The only way to achieve it is by modifying your htacess file that's currently located in your server.

```
# Force HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will work with your request.